# T-test Independence for a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I want to calculate the [scipy.stats.ttest_ind()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) for numeric columns in a pandas DataFrame with the binary target variable.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
```

```
def calculate_tStatistic(df, target, numeric_cols):

    """
    Calculate the t-test on TWO RELATED samples of scores, a and b.

    This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 related or 
    repeated samples have identical average (expected) values.

    Params
    =====================================
    df               : dataframe
    target           : target column name(str)
    numeric_cols     : list of numeric columns

    Return
    =======================================
    results_df       : A dataframe with features and t-statistic p-val
    """

    # create an empty dictionary
    t_test_results = {}
    # loop over column_list and execute code 
    for column in numeric_cols:
        group1 = df.where(df[target] == 0).dropna()[column]
        group2 = df.where(df[target] == 1).dropna()[column]
        # add the output to the dictionary 
        t_test_results[column] = stats.ttest_ind(group1,group2)
    results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(t_test_results,orient='Index')
    results_df.columns = ['t-statistic','t_stat_pval']

    results_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    results_df.rename(columns = {"index":"x"}, inplace=True)
    return results_df
```

**Sample**

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
```

```
calculate_tStatistic(titanic, "survived", ["age", "fare"])
```

**Results**

```
      x       t-statistic     t_stat_pval
0    age        3.479558       0.000630
1    fare      -1.767759       0.078795
```

**Can someone confirm that I'm actually doing it the right way?**

**Is there a better / more elegant / more accurate way to do this??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a bug in your code. Look at these two lines:

```py
        group1 = df.where(df[target] == 0).dropna()[column]
        group2 = df.where(df[target] == 1).dropna()[column]
```

What is happening here? First, the `where` method sets all rows in which your condition (`df[target] == 0`) is not true to `NaN`. Then, you drop the `NaN` values by using `dropna()`. The problem: The `dropna()` method removes all rows where at least one element is `NaN`, but this not only applies to the rows not meeting your condition, but also to other rows. For example, check out the `deck` column in the dataset, it has lots of rows with `NaN` values and all of them get completely removed (that is the *entire* row). This is not what you want, I guess.

My suggestion:

```py
        group1 = df.loc[df[target]==0, column].dropna()
        group2 = df.loc[df[target]==1, column].dropna()
```

This code first extracts the column of interest and then removes the `NaN` values. Not the other way around. In this way, you avoid removing too many lines. In addition, I use `loc` to select the values, as this is the preferred pandas method, when you need to index rows and columns simultaneously, as opposed to chained indexing like `df[idx1][idx2]`. Fore more details see here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

---

A thing I just learned: As an alternative to using the `dropna()` method, you can set the nan_policy to 'omit' when calling the `stats.ttest_ind` function:

```py
stats.ttest_ind(group1, group2, nan_policy='omit')
```